# Representing PSET as species

Tags: enumerative-combinatorics, generating-functions, species

In symbolic method, one often considers two operators on ordinary generating functions, namely

$$
\operatorname{PSET}F(x) = \exp\left(F(x)-\frac{F(x^2)}{2}+\frac{F(x^3)}{3}-\dots\right),
$$

and

$$
\operatorname{MSET}F(x) = \exp\left(F(x)+\frac{F(x^2)}{2}+\frac{F(x^3)}{3}+\dots\right).
$$

These operators allowed to enumerate sets (for $\operatorname{PSET}$) or multisets (for $\operatorname{MSET}$) constructed of *unlabeled* $F$-structures.

One may note that $\operatorname{MSET} F(x)$ is, essentially, unlabeled generating functions for the species $E \circ F$, where $E$ is the species of sets and $\circ$ denotes the composition of species. Correspondingly, the relevant exponential generating function would be $e^{F(x)}$.

Is there any meaningful way to interpret $\operatorname{PSET}$ in the terms of labeled species as well? Ideally, to get some formula for the exponential generating function of the labeled version of $\operatorname{PSET}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Gilbert Labelle, *[On asymmetric structures](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(92)90371-L)*, Discrete Math. 99 (1992), 141–164.

Comment: Oh, nice! So, PSET may be interpreted as flat part of $E \circ F$, if taken over flat parts of $F$. Although this is quite close to what I was asking for, I'm not sure it covers everything? I mean, PSET seems to be well-defined for any unlabeled species, not necessarily flat ones...

Comment: By the way, thanks for [this presentation](https://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/slides/species-intro.pdf), it contains a lot of invaluable examples and intuition, which I used to introduce species to my peers!